# Defining ELBO in Variational Inference with 3 random variables

Tags: variational-bayes, generative-models

I am reading [this](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/5352-semi-supervised-learning-with-deep-generative-models.pdf) paper, and having a hard time understanding one of the derivations. It is probably more of a stat question. The context is, having three random variables $x,y,z$, we would want to define the ELBO in two conditions, when only $z$ is latent (Eq.6), when both $y,z$ are latent (Eq.7). The first case is:

Eq.6: $-\mathcal{L}(x,y) = \mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{q_{
\phi}(z|x,y)}[\log P_\theta(x|y,z)+\log P_\theta(y)+\log P(z) - \log q_{
\phi}(z|x,y)]$

and the second case is:

Eq.7: $\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{q_{
\phi}(y,z|x)}[\log P_\theta(x|y,z)+\log P_\theta(y)+\log P(z) - \log q_{
\phi}(y,z|x)]$

The difference between the two is that in the second one $y$ is assumed to be latent, while in the first equation $y$ is observed. Now, based on the above two, they define :

$\mathop{\mathbb{E}}_{q_{
\phi}(y,z|x)}[\log P_\theta(x|y,z)+\log P_\theta(y)+\log P(z) - \log q_{
\phi}(y,z|x)] \\= \sum_y q_{\phi}(y|x)(-\mathcal{L}(x,y)) + \mathcal{H}(q_{\phi}(y|x))$

which I really can't derive from the two equations. I tried expanding RHS ($\sum_y q_{\phi}(y|x)(-\mathcal{L}(x,y)) + \mathcal{H}(q_{\phi}(y|x))$) to recover the LHS of Eq.7. But, no hope so far ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to merge the generative distribution for readability: $\log p_{\theta}(x,y,z) = \log p_{\theta}(x|yz) + \log p(y) + \log p(z)$.

Start by assuming the following decomposition of the variational distribution $q_{\phi}(y,z|x) = q_{\phi}(z|x,y)q_{\phi}(y|x)$ and let $z$ be continuous and $y$ discrete, we can write out the expectation.

\begin{align}
\log p(x) &\geq \mathbb{E}_{q_{\phi}(y,z|x)} [\log p_{\theta}(x, y, z) - \log q_{\phi}(y, z|x)]\\
&= \sum_y \int_z q_{\phi}(y|x) q_{\phi}(z|x,y) [\log p_{\theta}(x,y,z) - \log q_{\phi}(y|x) - \log q_{\phi}(z|x,y)]\\
&= \sum_y q_{\phi}(y|x) \left [ \int_z q_{\phi}(z|x,y) [\log p_{\theta}(x,y,z) - \log q_{\phi}(z|x,y)] - \log q_{\phi}(y|x) \right ]\\
&= \sum_y q_{\phi}(y|x) \left [ \int_z q_{\phi}(z|x,y) [\log p_{\theta}(x,y,z) - \log q_{\phi}(z|x,y)] \right ] - \sum_y q_{\phi}(y|x)\log q_{\phi}(y|x)\\
&= \sum_{y} q_{\phi}(y|x) (- \mathcal{L(x,y)}) + \mathcal{H}(q_{\phi}(y|x)) = - \mathcal{U}(x)
\end{align}

Comment: Nice, but it seems you have assumed two decompositions for $q(y,z|x)$ in $\mathbb{E}_{q(y,z|x)} [\log p(x, y, z) - \log q(y, z|x)]$, once as $q(y|x)q(z|x)$ to write the expectation, and once as $q(z|x,y)q(y|x)$ to expand the $\log q(y, z|x)$ where each corresponds to a particular graphical model over $x,y,z$ variables.

Comment: Yes, I have edited my answer to fix this issue.